# Table 'sk43' doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to create a register php which will check if the table users exist and if not then create it, if it does exist then it will put POST data inside the table then display it on the page in a table. But I get this error

```
<?php
$host   =   "[RETRACTED]"  ;;
$pass   =   "[RETRACTED]"  ;

$link  =  mysql_connect ( $host ,  $user ,  $pass );
if (! $link ) {
    die( 'Could not connect: '  .  mysql_error ());
}

$db_selected  =  mysql_select_db ( $db ,  $link );
if (! $db_selected ) {
    die ( 'Can\'t use $db : '  .  mysql_error ());
}

// do stuff





$query = "SELECT ID FROM `users` ";
$result = mysql_query($link, $query);

if(empty($result)) {
                $query = "CREATE TABLE `users`(
                          `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          PERMISSION_LEVEL int,
                          APPLICATION_COMPLETED int,
                          APPLICATION_IN_PROGRESS int,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
                          )";
                $result = mysql_query($link, $query);
}


mysql_query("insert into `users` (username, password) 
values
  ('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')")
or die(mysql_error());
echo "Done!!!!";

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `users`");


echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Username</th>
<th>Password</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['username'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['password'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";



$filename = "users/$userName.txt";
$dirname = dirname($filename);
if (!is_dir($dirname))
{
    mkdir($dirname, 0755, true);
}
 $myfile = fopen("$filename", "w");
 fclose($myfile);
mysql_close ( $link );
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of

```
$query = "SELECT ID FROM `users` ";
$result = mysql_query($link, $query);

if(empty($result)) {
                $query = "CREATE TABLE `users`(
                          `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          PERMISSION_LEVEL int,
                          APPLICATION_COMPLETED int,
                          APPLICATION_IN_PROGRESS int,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
                          )";
                $result = mysql_query($link, $query);
}
```

use this for check table is exist or not and create table

```
$query = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `users`(
                          `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
                          PERMISSION_LEVEL int,
                          APPLICATION_COMPLETED int,
                          APPLICATION_IN_PROGRESS int,
                          PRIMARY KEY  (ID)
                          )";
$result = mysql_query($link, $query);
```